# Convert array of dicts to timestamp-indexed DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

`ts` should be index (Unix time in milliseconds), column name is random string.

```
[
    {'ts': 1669246574000, 'value': '6.06'}, 
    {'ts': 1669242973000, 'value': '6.5'}
]
```

I would like to have the following output

```
DT index         SomeParam
1669242973000    6.5
1669246574000    6.06
```

Instead of

```
DT index    ts               SomeParam
0           1669242973000    6.5
1           1669246574000    6.06
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame( [ {'ts': 1669246574000, 'value': '6.06'}, 
    {'ts': 1669242973000, 'value': '6.5'}
])`

Comment: As I understand DataFrame format it would be 2-column frame with index 0,1...N

Comment: Use `pd.DataFrame(L).set_index('ts')`

Comment: @jezrael Great. Do you know how to replace `value` column name with `SomeParam`?

Comment: @jezrael I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-column-names-in-pandas) the answer